# Controlling what screenshot and title show up in Facebook profile after Like button is clicked

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-like

Below is a Facebook Like button.  I added the "href" part which redirects to a file I made.  I'm redirecting to this file in order to put an entry into a MySQL database recording everytime someone likes something.

It works well, but on the user's Facebook profile, the screenshot and title are both from the main page of my site (not the page with the Like button).  Is there any way that I could control the screenshot and title that shows up in the Facebook profile?

```
echo '<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www...com/.../fblike.php?submissionid='.$submissionid." send="true" layout="button_count" width="150" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that facebook has access to the liked page, so that it could pick the title and image. You could also add some special meta tags https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ if the title in images on the page are not enough.

Comment: How do I give Facebook access to it?

Comment: The page have to be publicly accessible

Comment: Okay... it's definitely public.  But it does have a header() at the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try opengraph protocol: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/
add:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Your title"/>
```

Comment: Should I put that on the page with the Like button, or the file that I'm using inside href (`fblike.php`)?

Comment: You should put it in file inside href.

Comment: @ codez  I tried that and it still just pulls the title tag from my domain's main page.

Comment: you should not redirect fblike.php with Header();

Comment: @ codez: how could I re-direct the user to another page from fblike.php?

Comment: 1) You can try to log likes to mysql in final page and href of that page put in fb:like  2)You can redirect with javascript: document.locatin='your_uri'